# implementing Parallel Radix Sort in C#

Tags: c#, sorting, parallel-processing, radix

I'm actually interested in implementing Parallel Radix Sort in C#, which is part of [MPSM(Massively Parallel Sort Merge) PDF file](http://vldb.org/pvldb/vol5/p1064_martina-cezaraalbutiu_vldb2012.pdf)  article.

A lot of single thread implementations of Radix Sort algorithm can be found, but no parallel for .Net.

I need a parallel version of Radix Sort in C#.

Comment: Looking at that document, the radix sort is part of the sort performed by each thread on it's portion of data. The document mentions using an in place radix sort for this based on the most significant byte, then using other sort methods to complete the sort on a portion of data. The key issue is with the merge and perhaps some clever way to separate the data at the start. I didn't read the document well enough to understand how it proposes to optimize the merge, but usually any merge operation is going to be memory bandwidth limited, so I'm not sure of the benefit of a multi-threaded merge.